# Can I fix Lost arbitrator node errors in MySQL Cluster / NDB?

Tags: mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I have a cluster of eight MySQL Cluster nodes running NDB. At seemingly random intervals (around 1.5 weeks on average, but they seem to come in spurts when they show up), I see a pair of messages like the following in ndb_${node_id}_out.log:

```
2016-08-11 06:45:25 [ndbd] INFO     -- Lost arbitrator node 1 - process failure [state=6]
2016-08-11 06:45:31 [ndbd] INFO     -- Prepare arbitrator node 1 [ticket=09770027de4ab90a]
```

For about fifteen seconds after that first message, all queries to the cluster fail with the message `Got error 157 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER`, which I gather from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522730/mysql-cluster-error-1296-hy000-got-error-157-unknown-error-code-from-ndbclu means we failed to connect.

I haven't been able to find any more information about this "Lost arbitrator" error or how to fix it. Is there a way to not lose my arbitrators?